# Is $\mathbb{Z}_+ = \{ 0, 1, 2, \dots \}$ or $\mathbb{Z}_+ = \{ 1, 2, \dots \}$?

Tags: notation

Is there complete consensus on which of these is true?

Comment: No. ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: I would say $\{1,2,\dots\}$ otherwise there is no distinction from $\mathbb{N}$. However, I would recommend $\mathbb{Z}_{>0}$ for example. But this is just my opinion.

Comment: @naslundx no distinction from $\Bbb N$? I have always used $\Bbb N$ to mean $\{1,2,3,\cdots\}$. For $\{0,1,2,3,\cdots\}$ I use $\Bbb W$. It's always like this in school here.

Comment: @Sabyasachi Interesting, I would say $0 \in \mathbb{N}$, but I might be wrong. Either way, one of the two alternatives would equal $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @naslundx yes one of the two would. Also it doesn't cause *that* much confusion, the intended set can almost always be inferred from context. Of course, $0$ *should* be in $\Bbb N$. There's nothing **unnatural** about it.

Answer (score 1):

most of the time $\mathbb{Z}_{+}$ is taken as $\{1,2,3,...\}$...for other the term $non-negative \ integers$ is used.

Comment: What is 'most of the time'?

Comment: actually it should be always...but some have doubts as Kenny LJ has.

Comment: I'm not saying you're wrong, just that you should include a link to a source that verifies your claim.

Comment: @naslundx http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NaturalNumber.html or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number...but again its a matter of convention.

Answer (score 1):

These notations haven't an universal agreement and just  know for example that the [Bourbaki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicolas_Bourbaki) notation for these sets
 (which's the notation adopted by the French mathematicians among other) is:

- $\Bbb N=\{0,1,2,\ldots\}$
- $\Bbb N^*=\{1,2,\ldots\}$
- $\Bbb Z_+=\Bbb N$